# how to get elements from a JSON from web service

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have a JSON object returned from a web service and I want to extract elements from the object, specifically the first element which is `id`?

```
[{"id":2,"type":"Asset",
  "assetNumber":"13723",
  "macAddress":null,"networkName":
  "13723imsmid8","model": 
 {"id":16,"type":"Model",
  "modelName":"M73","manufacturer":
 {"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}}, 
 {"id":3556,"type":"Asset",
  "assetNumber":"13723",
  "macAddress":null,
  "networkName":null,
  "model":{"id":16,"type":"Model",
  "modelName":"M73","manufacturer":
 {"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}}, 
 {"id":7196,"type":"Asset",
  "assetNumber":"13723",
  "macAddress":null,"networkName":null,
  "model":{"id":16,"type":"Model",
  "modelName":"M73","manufacturer":
  {"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},
  {"id":9720,"type":"Asset", 
   "assetNumber":"13723",
   "macAddress":null,"networkName":null,
   "model":{"id":16,"type":"Model","modelName":"M73",
   "manufacturer": {"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},
  {"id":11689,"type":"Asset",
   "assetNumber":"13723",
   "macAddress":null,
   "networkName":null,"
    model":{"id":68,"type":"Model",
    "modelName":"POC-W211","manufacturer": 
   {"id":19,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},{"id":11906,"type":"Asset",
    "assetNumber":"13723",
    "macAddress":null,
    "networkName":null,
    "model":{"id":71,"type":"Model",
    "modelName":"OptiPlex 780",
    "manufacturer":{"id":5,"type":"Manufacturer"}}}]
```

Comment: please check [mcve]

Comment: What have you tried? Post the code that you have so far.

Comment: Where is the detailed problem description and question? Take some time to read [ask]

Comment: I am surprised stack let you post this all code without providing more text (when I do this stack tells me something like: it looks like ti mostly code, please provide more text")

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array of data and extract the ID using an array map function:

```
const data = [{"id":2,"type":"Asset","assetNumber":"13723","macAddress":null,"networkName":"13723imsmid8","model":{"id":16,"type":"Model","modelName":"M73","manufacturer":{"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},{"id":3556,"type":"Asset","assetNumber":"13723","macAddress":null,"networkName":null,"model":{"id":16,"type":"Model","modelName":"M73","manufacturer":{"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},{"id":7196,"type":"Asset","assetNumber":"13723","macAddress":null,"networkName":null,"model":{"id":16,"type":"Model","modelName":"M73","manufacturer":{"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},{"id":9720,"type":"Asset","assetNumber":"13723","macAddress":null,"networkName":null,"model":{"id":16,"type":"Model","modelName":"M73","manufacturer":{"id":10,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},{"id":11689,"type":"Asset","assetNumber":"13723","macAddress":null,"networkName":null,"model":{"id":68,"type":"Model","modelName":"POC-W211","manufacturer":{"id":19,"type":"Manufacturer"}}},{"id":11906,"type":"Asset","assetNumber":"13723","macAddress":null,"networkName":null,"model":{"id":71,"type":"Model","modelName":"OptiPlex 780","manufacturer":{"id":5,"type":"Manufacturer"}}}];

const ids = data.map(item => item.id)
// returns an array of ids: [2, 10, 16, ...]
```

Comment: Sorry its in asp.net

Comment: @RayÓSé why isn't the question tagged with asp.net, and why is it tagged with JavaScript when you don't want solutions in JS?  **Tags matter**.

Answer (score 0):

Or,

```
var json = [{"id":2,"type":"Asset","assetNumber":"13723","macAddress":null,"networkName":"13723imsmid8","model":{"id":16,...';
var p = 0;
do {
    p=json.indexOf('"id":',p)+5;
    n=json.indexOf(',',p);
    alert(json.substr(p,(n-p)));
} 
while (json.indexOf('"id":',p)>0);
```